# Perl script to compare two files but print in order

Tags: perl, hash

I have followed this question [perl compare two file and print the matching lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862054/perl-compare-two-file-and-print-the-matching-lines) and found lines which match or dont match between two files using hash.

But I find that hash rearranges the lines and I want the lines in order. I can write multiple for loops to get results in order but this is not as efficient as hash. Has anyone faced this issue before and could please help with their solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done efficiently in two steps. Let's assume you have been able to find the "lines that match" but they are in the wrong order; then a simple `grep` can re-organize them. Assuming you have a script `matchThem` that takes two inputs (`file1` and `file2`) and outputs them to `tempFile`, then the over all script will be:

```
matchThem file1 file2 > tempFile
grep -Fx -f tempFile file1
```

The `-Fx` flag means:

```
-F : find exact match only (much faster than wildcards)
-x : only match whole lines
```

Comment: I could not get it working with "grep -Fx tempFile file1" but "fgrep -f tempFile file1" does the work .. Thanks @Floris

Comment: I have a short files to compare, so I dont much of a difference and only grep gives the output in order (which I need) .. But I found online that perl hash tables scale better for large log files ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490036/fast-alternative-to-grep-f

Comment: Interesting link - if you ever do run this on large files would you update us on the time difference?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe don't understand fully the question but

```
fgrep -xf file2 file1
```

is not enough?

or

```
fgrep -xf file1 file2
```

yes, it is not `perl` but, short simple and fast...

Comment: That is pretty short and sweet. Agree this should solve the whole problem without the intermediate perl. But there is a risk of partial matches. If you add the `-x` flag you only match whole lines, which is what the OP wanted, I think. It would be interesting to have a speed comparison vs his two-step approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an hash which keeps the insertion order, then try out the CPAN module [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-IxHash/).